# How do I rotate cols<->rows?

Tags: .net, linq

Here is some [example code with the correct output](http://ideone.com/cbs43g)

The idea is I require 6 rows. I don't care about how many columns I have. The IEnumerable are my columns. I'd like the first row to hold the first value of each IEnumerable. Second row hold the second etc. If there isn't enough values in the IEnumerable/column put -1 as a placeholder.

This code does it but I'm sure there is a linq statement I can use rather then implement it this way. Any idea how to do this using linq?

```
var mydata = new IEnumerable<int>[] { Enumerable.Range(2, 3), Enumerable.Range(5, 5), Enumerable.Range(7, 6), Enumerable.Range(3, 2) };
var temp = new List<int>[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    temp[i] = new List<int>();
foreach (var v in mydata)
{
    var len = v.Count();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6&&i<len; ++i)
    {
        temp[i].Add(v.ElementAt(i));
    }
    for (; i < 6; ++i)
        temp[i].Add(-1);
}
foreach (var outer in temp)
{
    foreach (var inner in outer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inner);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("---");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var mydata = new IEnumerable<int>[] { Enumerable.Range(2, 3), Enumerable.Range(5, 5), Enumerable.Range(7, 6), Enumerable.Range(3, 2) };
var maxLength = mydata.Max(l => l.Count());
var rotated = 
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, maxLength)
    select 
        from list in mydata
        select list.Skip(i).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First();
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var rotated = Enumerable.Range(0, maxLength)
    .Select(i => mydata.Select(l => l.Skip(i).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First()));
```

Now, this is not terribly efficient because it requires iterating each list numerous times. If you convert the input data to a list of arrays first, it should be a bit faster:

```
var myarray = mydata.Select(l => l.ToArray());
var maxLength = myarray.Max(l => l.Length);
var rotated = 
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, maxLength)
    select 
        from l in myarray
        select i < l.Length ? l[i] : -1;
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var rotated = Enumerable.Range(0, maxLength)
    .Select(i => myarray.Select(l => i < l.Length ? l[i] : -1));
```

Comment: That's...nice. And works! AND you don't need to hard-code the `6`.

Comment: You beat me to it! I was just typing a comment to ask how to do it in fluent syntax!

Answer (score 1):

You can have it in one line, however it won't be very readable:

```
var temp = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 6)
    .Select(i => mydata.Select(v 
        => i < v.Count() ? v.ElementAt(i) : -1).ToList())
    .ToArray();
```